# Recordset to iterate through database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an asp.net e-commerce application in which I am adding functionality of Discount:

if the `totalPurchase amount >=200, then 5% disc`,
if it `is >=500, then 7%..` Like that.

Problem is the discount % should be changed dynamically via Admin login. i.e. I am not allowed to write this code in code-behind.

```
if(totalPurchase>=200 && totalPurchase<700)
{ // code for 5% discount }
```

I am trying to implement recordet to iterate through database table Discount whose fields are..

```
DiscID -1

DiscPer -5

DiscAmount -200
```

and so on..

Comment: I didn't understand this part of the question **Problem is The discount % should be changed dynamically via admin log0in. i.e. I am not allowed to write**

Comment: The Admin can change the % of discount, discount on what amount dynamically. Means the code(back-end) need not to be changed every-time.

Comment: There should be a third column also to tell the limit from which this discount should be applicable. Example: 5% for 200+

Comment: yah ! I have thought about it. But what I really need is a code-behind to write recordset functionality, which will facilitate my scenario. Thanks, btw !

Comment: At least tell me whether I am going right?

Comment: Ok. Here's hint.. What i am thinking to implement...

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "";
    Recordset rs = new Recordset();

    if(totalPurchase>=rs(1))
    {
     // 5% discount code
    }

    else if(totalPurchase>=rs(1))
    {
     //7% discount code
    }

    else if(totalPurchase>=rs(1))
    {
    //so on..
    }

How to implement this? I really don't have idea about using recordset. Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you are missing a database column for storing your discount amount range like `200` to `700` etc. I am assuming the database table name to be `Discounts` and the range columns to be `AmountFrom` and `AmountTo`. Here is my solution for you:

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Data.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
connect.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT AmountFrom, AmountTo, DiscPer FROM Discounts";
command.Connection = connect;

OleDbReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{   
    int from = int.Parse(reader['AmountFrom'].toString());
    int to = int.Parse(reader['AmountTo'].toString());
    int discount = int.Parse(reader['DiscPer'].toString());

    if(totalPurchase >= from && totalPurchase < to) {
        MessageBox.Show("You got a discount of " + discount + "%");
    }
}
connect.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for time. But I clearly mentioned in my question that i don't want to write * if(totalPurchase>=200 && totalPurchase<700) * code, as the discount value may vary afterwords. So I am thinking to use recordset. Ask me for more details, I will provide you.

Comment: Ok. Here's hint.. What i am thinking to implement... SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(); conn.ConnectionString = ""; Recordset rs = new Recordset(); if(totalPurchase>=rs(1)) { // 5% discount code } else if(totalPurchase>=rs(1)) { //7% discount code } else if(totalPurchase>=rs(1)) { //so on.. } How to implement this? I really don't have idea about using recordset. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

This SO question may get you a good approach to your discounting problem [Database Design Brainstorming: Sale Prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036052/database-design-brainstorming-sale-prices)

Comment: Just found on Google that asp.net doesn't support recordset. I will use your code or go with dataset. Thank you.